# How to explicitely set right margin to a text

Tags: vertical-alignment

[image]

I am interested in setting a right margin for the date *2014* on the same line with *National Olympiad of Informatics* to be vertically aligned with the date above it and have a similar format.

I have tried to use `\hfill` i.e:

```
\item{
  \textbf{National Olympiad of Informatics}
  \hfill{2014}
}
```

But as you probably noticed from the aforementioned image the text is pushed a little bit too much to the right creating a discrepancy in the alignment.

Is there any way that I can set a right-margin for an individual item? Is there any way that I can generalize that right-margin for more any item?

Code:

```
% -------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Sourabh Bajaj
% Website: https://github.com/sb2nov/resume
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.35}


%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{\Large {UHUU SOMBODY}} \\
  \\
    \textcolor{mygray}{\large Curriculum Vitae} &  Email   :  ....@soton.ac.uk\\
    &  Mobile   :   (+40) ..--..--7138 \\
   & Address    :   UK, Southampton Burgess Road, .... .... 
\end{tabular*}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {University of Southampton}{Southampton, UK}
      {Bachelor of Mathematics with Computer Science }{Oct. 2018 -- July. 2021}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Modules Covered 1st Year}{Programming I \& II, Algorithmics, Calculus, Linear Algebra I \& II, Multivariable Calculus, Statistics, Operational Research I and Mathematical Computing}
      \resumeItemListEnd
    \resumeSubheading
      {Filadelfia Theoretical High School}{Suceava, Romania}
      {Mathematics and Computer Science Diploma with GPA of 9.85/10.0}{2014 -- 2018}
      \resumeItemListStart
              \item{

            \textbf{National Olympiad of Informatics}
            \hfill{2014}

        }
        \resumeItem{National Physics Contest}{\textit{Marin Dacian Bica}, Silver Medal (2015)}
        \item{\textbf{Baccalaureate Diploma} with GPA of 9.41/10.0 (2018)}
      \resumeItemListEnd
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {Center of Excellence in Informatics}{Suceava, Romania}
      {Teaching assistant \& Member}{Dec. 2017}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Teaching assistant}
          {I helped children aged 13 to 15 achieve great results in Informatics Olympiads, teaching them C++ and OOP in Visual Studio - C\#.}

    \resumeItem{Member}
          {Member of a team (formed by the top 15 high-school students in the county) that developed technology to be presented at the interantional conference \textbf{\textit{Space for Science - Implementing Innovations in Science Education.}} }

      \resumeItemListEnd

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-----------PROJECTS-----------------
\section{Projects}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubItem{International Young Scientist Conference \textit{Space for Science} - Norway\textit{ (2015)}}
      {Used my knowledge of Physics and Computer Science to build a wind turbine generator from scratch. Developed my social skills and became more aware of contemporary problems such as renewable and suistanable energy.
      }
    \resumeSubItem{Smart Home Simulator in Java\textit{ (2018)}}
      {The  aim  of  this  coursework  was  to  construct  a simulation  of  the energy  consumption --  and energy generation -- of a smart house. Developed my Object Oriented Programming (OOP) concepts The gist of the coursework was to improve our OOP concepts.}
%     \resumeSubItem{Mac Setup}
%       {Book that gives step by step instructions on setting up developer environment on Mac OS.}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%
%--------PROGRAMMING SKILLS------------
\section{Programming Skills}
 \resumeSubHeadingListStart
 \setlength\itemsep{0.01em}
   \item{
     \textbf{Intermediate}{: C++, Java, C\#}
   }

   \item{
     \textbf{Basic}{: Python, R, HTML5, CSS, MySQL \& Database Management}
   }
   \item{
    \textbf{\textit{Original European Computer Driving License:}}
        \resumeSubHeadingListStart
            \resumeItem{Security for IT Users}{IT User Fundamentals}
            \resumeItem{Advanced Word Processing, Spreadsheets, Database, Presentation}{(\textit{Microsoft Office 2010)}}
        \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
   }
 \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\section{Linguistic \hfill Certificates}

    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \setlength\itemsep{0.01em}
    \item{ 
    \textbf{Romanian} (native language)
    \hfill
    \textbf{Certificate of Language Proficiency}

    }
    \item{
        \textbf{English} (fluent)
        \hfill
        \textbf{Certificate in Advanced English - C1}
    }
    \item{
        \textbf{Italian} (basic phrases and words)
    }
        \item{
        \textbf{German} (beginner)
    }

    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\section{Interests}
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \item{ 
        \textbf{Sports}
        \resumeSubHeadingListStart
            \item{Member of Men's second Team of Volleyball - University of Southampton
            \hfill
            \textit{2018 Oct. -- Present}
            }
        \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
    }
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

> EDIT: Another issue would arise if I increased the value of the
>   \textwidth as @Sigur mentioned in the comments. The dot from the
>   dotted list would be pushed upwards for a strange reason. Do you have
>   any solutions for this issue?

Image:
[image: Dot item list issue]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a complete (yet minimal) code?

Comment: How you inserted the previous text? We need to see more code. Please, give us a MWE.

Comment: Editing the post right now

Comment: @Ryk Please paste your code here in your future posts. People here don't like following external links, as they can be down at any moment.

Comment: On line 56 of your code, increase a little bit the width, for example, `0.98\textwidth`

Comment: For the font size, use `{\small\textit{2014}}`

Comment: @Sigur If you don't mind can you be roughly more specific where I should insert this `0.98\textwidth` piece of code?

Comment: In `\resumeSubheading` definition around line 56, there is a tabular: `\begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}`. Replace the value `0.97` by `0.98`.

Comment: @Sigur Another issue would arise if I increased the value of the `\textwidth`. The dot from the dotted list would be pushed upwards for a strange reason. Do you have any solutions for this issue?

Comment: Well, not the best solution, but could be satisfactory for a while. Use `{.975\textwidth}[t]` (pay attention to `[t]`)

Comment: @Sigur I tried `{.979\textwidth}[t]` and it looks promising whereas if I use `{.98\textwidth}[t]` everything goes out of place. This is so strange.

Comment: @Ryk, it is not strange. The length can not be near `\textwidth` since there is an extra space used by the item label (the bullet). So, the length of the table should be smaller. The problem is to determine its maximum value. Since I don't remember the value of the item label width, I can not tell you the right value for the table.

Comment: @Sigur In any case, the layout seems to be alright now, thanks!